# What's the difference between these two types of query writing?

Tags: mysql, sql

In relation to writing SQL queries, I could fetch something that I need in two ways:

Type 1:

```
select 
    cl.id 
from 
    datahub_clients             cl,
    datahub_client_accounts     cl_ac,
    datahub_accounts            ac    
where
    cl.id=cl_ac.client_id
    and
    ac.id=cl_ac.account_id
    and
    ac.account_no_dataphile="7H0010A1"
;
```

Type 2:

```
select 
    cl.id 
from 
    datahub_clients             cl
    join
    datahub_client_accounts     cl_ac
    on
    cl.id=cl_ac.client_id
    join
    datahub_accounts            ac    
    on
    ac.id=cl_ac.account_id
where
    ac.account_no_dataphile="7H0010A1"
;
```

Following are the few queries in my mind:
1) Is there any difference between how the SQL compiler interprets them?
2) Should there be preference around any one? (Why?)
3) From scalability perspective, which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type 2:

select 
    cl.id 
from 
    datahub_clients             cl
    join
    datahub_client_accounts     cl_ac
    on
    cl.id=cl_ac.client_id
    join
    datahub_accounts            ac    
    on
    ac.id=cl_ac.account_id
where
    ac.account_no_dataphile="7H0010A1"
```

is better because table name with comma separated create cross join( which is costly in terms of performance) between all those tables so it should be need to avoid

Type-1 is old method of join which strongly discourage to use